# Is it legal to intercept a web request from a website that is not mine to feed a web page?

Tags: javascript

I hope you do not mark my question as a negative, I do not have a clear answer and this can give feedback to several users and avoid doing something wrong (if that were the case)

I would like to know the experience of someone with experience in this subject. Basically I have to make a website that offers information about several car dealers, and I have to make my page integrate the different offers of vehicles so that my page makes a comparison and the user can make a final decision.

Personally I have informed myself and I have understood that it is something unethical, but there are also people who have told me that the fact that I can intercept the web service is legal because it is free for the simple fact of being in the cloud.

Could you please tell me if this is legal, or well seen? And if it were not legal, what path could I do to fulfill the purpose of this web page that I should build?

Note: I would not be consuming an API, I would be directly copying the webservice from some car dealership (I would use the url and send the correct parameters to send the information I need.

Comment: This is called web scraping, and usually what happens is the target recognise what you are doing and blocks you. Anyway there is loads of online discussion about this. It probably comes down to the terms of usage of the site.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid thanks..I appreciate your response. but I'm in the same point XD. What could I do?

Comment: Also known as Screen Scraping. There are many methods out there for performing this, both server side and client side. Server side is probably the best way to do this from a technical standpoint. Try searching for articles on Screen Scraping for your server side technology stack. It is very much ethically in a gray area and as @Nick.McDermaid said, from a legal standpoint it will come down to the terms and conditions of the sites you are scraping. As to circumventing any Terms and Conditions, that is not a programming issue and falls outside StackOverflow's scope.

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about crawling/scraping. This is done in a variety of ways and for a variety of reasons; for example, search engines crawl websites so they can index them. Now, the business case here is that a search engine benefits from having a large index and having the ability to successfully respond to queries by sending users to appropriate destinations. The benefit for those websites, obviously, is improved discoverability and traffic. Not to mention, there's an advertising network and platform that accompanies all of this, where search engines and business both benefit from presence and partnership.

In the case of search engine crawlers, however, the site owner is in charge of whether search engines should crawl their site. They can set parameters--on the site itself, or on a dashboard in the search engine management console--to prevent crawlers from indexing the site.

So, you see, there's no easy, one-size-fits-all answer here. But here are a few topics you can ponder, and a few questions you can ask:

1. Are your target sites open to letting you crawl/scrape their content? To begin, check out their terms of use; sometimes they have clear language prohibiting any crawling/scraping/indexing. If that's the case, honor their wish and leave them alone.
2. What value will you offer them? By aggregating their content, will you link back to their site, creating some traffic and potential business for them? Will you show their desired attribution and branding along with the content you show from them? Will you allow them to opt out if they so desire?
3. If unsure, reach out to them. Explain what you're trying to do, and offer them clear benefits through partnership with you. If they are open to working with you, get a written statement from them that states you are allowed to scrape and use their content in the fashion that you and they have agreed to.